# Finding $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t-2|}{t}$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{|t-2|}{t}$

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

Find $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t-2|}{t}$$ and $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{|t-2|}{t}$$

Usually I would simply the top and bottom but I'm not sure what to do for absolute values.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT : Note that 
$$|t-2|=\begin{cases}t-2&\text{if $t-2\ge 0$}\\-(t-2)&\text{if $t-2\lt 0$}\end{cases}$$
Hence, we have
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t-2|}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-(t-2)}{t}$$
and

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{|t-2|}{t}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t-2}{t}.$$

Comment: Okay, thanks. How would I solve for g'(1) and g'(2)? I'm not sure how the prime works with limits?

Comment: @androidguy: We have $g'(a)=\lim_{t\to a}\frac{g(t)-g(a)}{t-a}$.

Comment: Okay, so it would look like g'(1) = lim t->1 g(1) - g(1) / 1 - 1?

Comment: @androidguy: No. $g(t)=\frac{|t-2|}{t}$, right? If so, we have$$g'(1)=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{\frac{|t-2|}{t}-1}{t-1}.$$

Comment: Ahh, okay. That makes sense. So then do the same for g'(2)?

Comment: @androidguy: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for the help. I'm also asked to find slope for the tangent line as it varies from 0 to 4. Not sure how to do this? Sorry but I'm pretty new with tangent.

Comment: @androidguy: Well, why don't you finish this question by accepting an answer and ask it as a new question? That should be the best for you (and for me).

Comment: Okay, just gave you the green check and asked a new question. Thanks!